# Una lista de objetos (clases) me imprime la ubicación en memoria en Python

Tags: python, array, poo

buenas, estaba realizando un código que de manera básica, maneja el stock de una maquina expendedora de bebidas, pero como requisito, las bebidas debían ser objetos. Una vez creadas, quería manejarlas mediante una lista, y verificar la cantidad (que era el segundo requisito, emitir una alerta cuando hubieran menos de 5, y podían haber máximo 20) como un atributo del objeto, no se si será muy complicado, pero no logre imprimir la información  de la lista, ya que me imprime la ubicación en memoria y no los datos. Como podría solucionar esto¿?

```
class Producto ():
def __init__(self,cantidad,presentacion,id):
    self.__cantidad=cantidad
    self.__presentacion=presentacion
    self.__id=id
#Metodos Getters
def get_cantidad(self):
    return self.__cantidad
def get_presentacion(self):
    return self.__presentacion
def get_id(self):
    return self.__id
#Metodos Setters
def set_cantidad(self,cantidad):
    self.__cantidad=cantidad
def set_presentacion(self,presentacion):
    self.__presentacion=presentacion
def set_id(self,id):
    self.__id=id
#Metodos
def mostrar_datos(self):
    print(f"El ID es: {self.__id}")
    print(f"La presentación es: {self.__presentacion}")
    print(f"La cantidad en Stock es: {self.__cantidad}")
    return self.__presentacion,self.__cantidad


from Producto import Producto
class Tienda():
def __init__ (self, *listaproductos):
    self.__listaproductos=listaproductos
#Getters
def get_lista(self):
    return self.__listaproductos
#Setters
def set_lista(self,listaproductos):
    self.__listaproductos=listaproductos
#Metodos
def mostrar_stock():
    for i in range(len(listaproductos)):
        print(f"Stock: {listaproductos[i]}\n")
#def contar_stock():
    #Extraer un elemento de la lista, revisar si su cantidad es menor que 5, emitir mensaje en pantalla.
#def añadir_stock(self,stock):
    #Añadir mas stock a los elementos de la lista, extraer el que se va a modificar, e insertar nuevamente en la posición inicial.
#def eliminar_stock():
    #Eliminar el stock de un elemento de la lista, extraer el que se va a modificar, e insertar nuevamente en la posicion inicial.

Lata1=Producto(20,"Lata 333cc",1)
Botella=Producto(20,"Botella 591cc",2)
Bebida=Producto(20,"Bebida 2,5 litros",3)
listaproductos=[Lata1,Botella,Bebida]
Tiendita=Tienda(listaproductos)
Tienda.mostrar_stock()
```

Comment: Debes usar `Tiendita.mostrar_stock()`.

Comment: Si, lo uso, pero aun asi me muestra las direcciones de memoria, no los atributos

Comment: cual deseas que rea el resultado deseado? o como quieres que lo imprima?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si lo que quieres es pasar tus objetos a string puedes utilizar el metodo de clase `__str__`

solo basta con agregarlo a tu clases `Producto`

ejemplo:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f" {self.__id} {self.__presentacion} {self.__cantidad}"
```

si quieres acceder directo a los attributos seria definir los attributos de clase con una nomeclatura de variables **ADECUADA**.

la sintaxis que utilizas solo es para metodos **Especiales** como lo es `__init__()` o en este caso `__str__()`

ejemplo:

```
class Producto ():
    cantidad=None
    presentacion=None
    id=None
    def __init__(self,cantidad,presentacion,id):
    #resto del codigo
```

ahora para acceder a ellos seria:

```
def mostrar_stock():
        for i in range(len(listaproductos)):
            print(f"Stock: {listaproductos[i].cantidad} {listaproductos[i].presentacion}  {listaproductos[i].id}\n")
```

nota: cambie los nombres de variables que utilizas, ya que rompen con los estandares del lenguaje.